# Overlapping edge ticks when using custom ticks

Tags: python, matplotlib, color-mapping

EDIT: I removed everything from the code, which is ultimately not necessary. Bug still persists with MultipleLocator, however does not show up with MaxNLocator.

i am currently stuck with a small visual bug that occurred when i upgraded to matplotlib 1.4.3. I am using python 2.7.3 on ubuntu 12.04. I have a one row, two column plot with two heatmaps. Both are forced to share the same range of values for the colormap. I normalize the colormap so that the absolute values of vmin and vmax are equal but have opposite signs. When i try to use now custom ticks generated by MaxNLocator or MultipleLocator, there are two overlapping ticks displayed at one or both edges of the colorbar.

Here is a minimal code to reproduce the problem:

```
#setup
#make scripts executable when logged in per ssh (no x-window)
import matplotlib
# Force matplotlib to not use any Xwindows backend.
matplotlib.use('Agg')
#other setup
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import argparse
from matplotlib import ticker
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize
#
class MidpointNormalize(Normalize):
    def __init__(self, vmin=None, vmax=None, midpoint=None, clip=False):
        self.midpoint = midpoint
        Normalize.__init__(self, vmin, vmax, clip)

    def __call__(self, value, clip=None):
        # I'm ignoring masked values and all kinds of edge cases to make a
        # simple example...
        x, y = [self.vmin, self.midpoint, self.vmax], [0, 0.5, 1]
        return np.ma.masked_array(np.interp(value, x, y))
#first row first column plot
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2)
#plt.subplot(121)
#declare filename
data = np.random.rand(10,10)
data2 = np.random.rand(10,10)
cmapmin = -0.4
cmapmax = 0.4
cmap="jet"
norm = MidpointNormalize(midpoint=0.0, vmin=cmapmin, vmax=cmapmax)
axes[0].pcolor(data, edgecolors='k', vmin=cmapmin, vmax=cmapmax, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
im = axes[1].pcolor(data2, edgecolors='k', vmin=cmapmin, vmax=cmapmax, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
#give room for colorbar
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.1, wspace=0.1, hspace=0.1)
cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.95, 0.8, 0.04])
cb = fig.colorbar(im, cax=cbar_ax, orientation='horizontal')
#only use limited number of ticks as specified
tick_locator = ticker.MaxNLocator(nbins=8)
#set ticks every specified tickrange 
#tick_locator = ticker.MultipleLocator(base=0.1)
cb.locator = tick_locator
cb.update_ticks()
#save file
fig.savefig("example1.png")
```

Now the example1.png looks like this:
[image: using MaxNLocator]

When i comment out the line `tick_locator = ticker.MaxNLocator(nbins=8)` and use instead `tick_locator = ticker.MultipleLocator(base=0.1)` the image (example2.png) looks like this:

[image: using MultipleLocator]

I hope, my revised question helps you to get on the right track.

I would be very grateful for any input leading to a solution for this error, as so far my only other option is to use MaxNLocator with prune="both" to clip the edge ticks.
Thanks in advance

Comment: could you post an actual **minimal** example? For example, reading in command line arguments is not relevant to your problem with ticks, which seems to be more about how you use `ticker.MultipleLocator`, etc.

Comment: i have changed my post appropriately. Hope this helps answering the question, as the bug still shows up with MulitpleLocator.

Comment: Using `prune="both"` is the answer.

Comment: @cphlewis, unlike `MaxNLocator`, `MultipleLocator` doesn't have a keyword argument `prune`, so that doesn't solve the problem here